# Combining 2 dataframes of different structure

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There are 2 dataframes of different structures , I want to combine them to make a dataframe that has columns from both of them.
Example :

DF1 Has Columns A, B, C with 10 rows

DF2 has COlumns A, B, D, E, F with 12 rows

DF_final should be A, B, C, D, E, F with 22 rows.

DF1:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 5 | 6 |

DF2:

| A | B | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| 7 | 8 | 9 | 2 | 4 |

DF_Final:

| A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |  |  |  |
| 4 | 5 | 6 |  |  |  |
| 2 | 3 |  | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| 5 | 6 |  | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| 7 | 8 |  | 9 | 2 | 4 |

I tried
final_df = pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True)

But getting error  MismatchedDataFrameException: Expected DataFrame with columns:

Comment: Which version of pandas are you using? It works fine for me with 2.0.1

Comment: `result = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)`

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
df_final = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=0)
```

*OR*

```
df_final = df1.merge(df2, on=['A', 'B'], how='outer')
```